# Regex contains one or more phone number

Tags: java, php, regex

I need a regular expression that will match one or more phone numbers that can be separated by semicolons (`;`) and the number length can be 7 or more characters `0-9` and `+`, `-`, `_`.

Like the following:

```
1234567
1234567;1234567
1234567;+0591234567
1234567777;1234567777;1234567891
```

I've tried the following regular expression, but it failed:

```
^[0-9.-_+]{7,}(;[0-9.-_+]{7,})*$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: You need to be more precise about what you are trying to do, and show how you are using this regex. If I guessed your intentions then it should work: https://regex101.com/r/WP4p6F/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost correct just you need to use \ (back slash) before the characters which are used in regexp. Try it-

```
^[0-9.\-_+]{7,}(;[0-9.\-_+]{7,})*$
```

**UPDATE:**

It's more perfect than the previous-

```
(?<=\;|\A)[\+\-\_]?\d{7,}(?=\;|\Z)
```

You may try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/M4TFes/3). Credit goes to [@sudoman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3470343/sudoman)'s comment.

Comment: Only `-` is special in `[..]` since it can be used to create range of characters like `a-z`. We we don't need to escape `.` or `+` there.

Comment: And you don't need to escape `-` if it's the last character

Comment: '+' character is used in regexp as 1 to INF repetitions, '-' is used to mention a range, '.' is used to mention any character. So you need to escape them.

Comment: `[a+]` means `a` OR `+` characters, not `a` `aa` `aaa` because `[...]` can match SINGLE character from specified set of characters. We are *allowed* to use `\+` inside `[...]` (which I don't like because it creates only confusion like this one) but that doesn't mean this ``\`` is *required*.

Comment: Consider visiting http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special to get more info about `[...]` metacharacters.